# navigation between component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I need to navigate between two view in React Native. But the problem is my component where the button to navigate is on an other component. I use the react-navigation.

Let me show you :

I have my component MainPage here

```
class MainPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>
              <ComponentWithButton /> 
          </View>
  }
}
```

So in my component ComponentWithButton :

```
class ComponentWithButton extends Component {
      goToComponent(){
         this.props.navigation.push('Next')
      }
      render() {
        return <View style={styles.container}>
                  <Button onPress={this.goToComponent.bind(this)}/> 
              </View>
      }
    }
```

My next component is called `NextComponent`.

I have the error undefined is not an object (evaluating "this.props.navigation.push")

My stack navigator is this :

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainPage
    },
    Next: {
      screen: NextComponent
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Main"
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: { visible: false }
    }
  }
);
```

I try to run my code with just one component it's working perfectly. I think there is problem because `ComponentWithButton` is not called in my `RootStack` or something like that. I don't know I am a newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you didn't pass the navigation props to the 
`<ComponentWithButton />`

do something like this

`<ComponentWithButton navigation={this.props.navigation}/>`

also the method should be

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Next')`

if I recall

Comment: @Yapoto if its the right answer please check it so I get the cred

Comment: You are too fast, just wait 2min ;)

Answer (score 3):

react-navigation has a function withNavigation that populate navigation props in any of your Component. Just use it like that:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class ComponentWithButton extends Component {
      goToComponent(){
         this.props.navigation.push('Next')
      }
      render() {
        return <View style={styles.container}>
                  <Button onPress={this.goToComponent.bind(this)}/> 
              </View>
      }
}

export default withNavigation(ComponentWithButton);
```

Comment: I don’t know but I think so!